# Inserting data into SQLite database via Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm not getting any errors but when I'm checking my database in SQLite. it shows empty set. What should I do?

class mine:

## initializing

```
def __init__ (self):

    self.name = ""
    self.age = 0
    self.weight = 0.0
    self.height = 0.0
    self.gender = ""
    self.email = ""
    self.password = "'
```

## main function

```
def sign_up (self):


    self.name = raw_input ("Enter your first Name :")
    self.email = raw_input ("Enter A Valid Email id :")

    length = int(input ("How long do you want your password to be ? : "))
    chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'

    for c in range (length):
        self.password += random.choice(chars)
        print
        print "Your Special Password is :" , self.password

    print
    self.gender = raw_input ("enter your Gender (male / female) :")
    self.age = input ("Enter Your Age :")
    self.weight = input ("Enter Your Weight :")
    self.height = input ("Enter Your Height :")
    print
    print "Information Saved..."
    print
```

## database part starts here

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
    c = conn.cursor()



    params = (self.name, self.email, self.password, self.gender, self.age, 
              self.weight, self.height)

    c.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", params)
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: "Checking my database in mysql" No your not using MySQL.. I've change the database tag into SQLite because of this code `conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')`

Comment: Possible issue with data types? What is the schema of the table you're attempting to insert to?

Comment: Also, why not wrap the code in a try block and try to catch the error? http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/error-handling/python-try-and-except

Comment: Txtspk _and_ urgent begging on Stack Overflow - I admire your optimism!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a cursor to insert data, which is not needed in `sqlite3`:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
params = (self.name, self.email, self.password, self.gender, self.age, 
          self.weight, self.height)

conn.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", params)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```